# Problems using the maxlength attribute on text input in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to using the maxlength attribute on an input field. below is my component HTML.

```html
<div class="input-box-wrapper d-f" *ngIf="info[1] == false; else password">
    <label class="lable" for="{{info[4]}}">{{info[0]}}</label>
    <input class="p-10px c-w" type="{{info[3]}}" id="{{info[4]}}" placeholder="{{info[2]}}" maxlength="{{info[6]}}" (blur)="getValue($event)">
    <div>{{info[6]}} that works fine</div>
</div>

<ng-template #password>
    <div class="input-box-wrapper d-f p-r">
        <label class="lable" for="{{info[4]}}">{{info[0]}}</label>
        <input class="p-10px c-w" type="{{info[3]}}" #password1 id="{{info[4]}}" placeholder="{{info[2]}}" (blur)="getValue($event)">
        <i class="fa fa-eye-slash p-a icon" aria-hidden="true" #icon1 (click)="chnageIcon()"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-eye p-a icon show" aria-hidden="true" #icon2 (click)="chnageIcon()"></i>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

> I'm getting the following error:

[image: error image]

If I set a fixed maxlength (ex. maxlength="10") everything works fine. It seems a bug to me, but please let me know if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: use  `[maxlength]="info[6]"` and also for other binded attributes. also, add `FormsModule` in module `imports:[],` part.

Comment: @Mazdak still error

Comment: only info[6] not working on maxlenth that's works on `<div>info[6]</div>` too

Comment: I was wrong `[attr.minlength]="min"` is ok because `minlength` is attribute, not a native property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpolation and property binding can set only properties, not attributes.
`maxlength` is an attribute not a native property that's why you get above error.

Check [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding)

> Use attribute binding `[attr.maxlength]="variable_name"`

```
<input class="p-10px c-w" type="{{info[3]}}" id="{{info[4]}}" placeholder="{{info[2]}}" [attr.maxlength]="info[6]" (blur)="getValue($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of writing this is :

```
<input class="p-10px c-w" type="{{info[3]}}" id="{{info[4]}}" placeholder="{{info[2]}}" [maxLength]="info[6]" (blur)="getValue($event)">
```

And in a general manner you can use the brackets around an attribute and use directly a variable instead of using the interpolation.

For instance you could have written :

```
<input class="p-10px c-w" [type]=info[3] [id]=info[4] [placeholder]=info[2] [maxLength]=info[6] (blur)="getValue($event)">
```